# error 1215 cannot add foreign key constraint symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I have a problem with symfony in creating relationship between my entities. I wish to make a ManyToOne relationship between my body and my body Registration University. An inscription is linked to a university.

class inscription:

```
/**
* Inscription
*
* @ORM\Table(name="Inscription")
*     @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="IEPA\PlatformBundle\Repository\InscriptionRepository")
*/
class Inscription
{
/**
* @ORM\Id
* @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=true)
* @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
*/
private $id;
/**
* @var integer
* 
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="IEPA\PlatformBundle\Entity\Universites")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
*/
private $univInsc;
}
```

class universites:

```
/**
* Universites
*
* @ORM\Table(name="universites")
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="IEPA\PlatformBundle\Repository\UniversitesRepository")
*/
class Universites
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;
}
```

When I update the database (php app / console doctrine : schema : update --force ) , I get the following error:

[image]

```
[Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\DriverException]
An exception occured while executing `ALTER TABLE inscription ADD CONTRAINT FK_D80C7901C5E240F6 FOREIGN KEY (univ_insc_id) REFERENCE universites (id):
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

Comment: Solution: j'ai désactivé la vérification de la clé étrangère en tapant la requête (php app / console doctrine : schema : update --dump-sql ) + set foreign_key_checks=0, directement dans MySQL

Answer (score 2):

Verify if you have already insert lines in your Inscription entity. if yes, remove him or if you can't delete them because your site was on line.

change this line like this :

```
@ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
```

to

```
@ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
```

And add inversedBy="inscriptions" to $univInsc like this :

```
@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="IEPA\PlatformBundle\Entity\Universites", inversedBy="inscriptions")
```

and try to execute doctrine:update again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There is no insert lines in my Inscription entity, only in Universites. With your solution i still have the same issue. I don't really understand what your "inscriptions" refered to.

Answer (score 0):

To do that, you've to declare the relation in both entities. One in ManyToOne and the other one with a OneToMany. And say Doctrine the way to reverse the data :

```
    /**
    * Inscription
    *
    * @ORM\Table(name="Inscription")
    *     @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="IEPA\PlatformBundle\Repository\InscriptionRepository")
    */
    class Inscription
    {
    /**
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=true)
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
    private $id;
    /**
    * @var integer
    * 
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="IEPA\PlatformBundle\Entity\Universites", inversedBy="inscriptions")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="idInscription", referencedColumnName="idInscription")
    */
    private $univInsc;
    }
```

Au niveau de ton université, on aura tes inscriptions qui seront référencées :

---

And on your University, we add a collection of Inscription :

```
    /**
    * Universites
    *
    * @ORM\Table(name="universites")
    * @ORM\Entity
    * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="IEPA\PlatformBundle\Repository\UniversitesRepository")
    */
    class Universites
    {
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

/**
 * @var Collection
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="IEPA\PlatformBundle\Entity\Inscription", mappedBy="univInsc")
 */
    private $inscriptions;
    }
```

Just a little thing : Naming convention is to name the entities with a Singular word. You can use a plural but I recommend you to do not use both  in the same project.

Comment: Premièrement, merci pour ta réponse. Il s'agit peut-être d'une mauvaise compréhension de ma part (je débute en symfony), mais je ne souhaite pas mettre en place de relation bidirectionnel. 
PS: j'ai essayé également avec ta solution et je retombe sur la même erreur.

Comment: Je te suggérais d'utiliser la bidirectionnalité parce que ça ne coûte pas plus cher (avec le lazy load de doctrine) et que ça peut bien t'aider par la suite. Après si tu juges ne jamais avoir besoin de retrouver tes inscriptions par université, soit. Pour ce qui est de ton erreur, je pense que c'est un problème d'ordre dans la pile d'exécution des requêtes que Doctrine essaye de lancer. Essaye de faire un `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql` et d'exécuter cette requette directement dans mysql.

Comment: D'accord je comprend mieux ta solution du bidirectionnnel :). Sa ne change rien il me bloque toujours sur l'ajout de clé étrangère.

Comment: Oui, lorsque tu fais du Symfony il ne faut pas penser la conception comme en Merise ^^. Bon sinon je vois encore 2 choses qui peuvent fortement dérange Doctirne : 1: Le nullalble=true sur on id de Inscription. 2: le I majuscule sur le @ORM\Table. Mets une minuscule comme dans ta base.

Comment: Toujours rien :( je vais tout reprendre au propre et poster si je trouve la solution. merci encore

Comment: Salut, as-tu trouvé la solution à ton problème ?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because the `foreign key constraint` already exists.

Try deleting the `foreign key constraint` on the owning (many to one) side of things directly. Once that's deleted, re-run your **doctrine CLI command** to execute the SQL changes. In ZF2, that's `php index.php orm:schema-tool:update --force` command and it'll recreate the index.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem after dump some tables for other project and the problem was the collation. The old tables where in utf8_unicode_ci and the new tables in utf8mb4_unicode_ci, so I changed it in doctrine.yaml.

From:

```
    doctrine:
        dbal:
            # configure these for your database server
            driver: 'pdo_mysql'
            server_version: '5.7'
            charset: utf8mb4
            default_table_options:
                charset: utf8mb4
                collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

To:

```
    doctrine:
        dbal:
            # configure these for your database server
            driver: 'pdo_mysql'
            server_version: '5.7'
            charset: utf8
            default_table_options:
                charset: utf8
                collate: utf8_unicode_ci
```

and...  Updating database schema...

```
 5 queries were executed
```

[OK] Database schema updated successfully!